# Combine multiple classifiers to build a multi-modal classifier

Tags: classification, svm

Suppose I am interested in classifying a set of instances composed by different content types, e.g.:

- a piece of **text**
- an **image**

as `relevant` or `non-relevant` for a specific class `C`.

In my classification process I perform the following steps:

1. Given a sample, I subdivide it in text and image
2. A first SVM binary classifier (`SVM-text`), trained only on text, classifies the text as `relevant`/`non-relevant` for the class `C`
3. A second SVM binary classifier (`SVM-image`), trained only on images, classifies the image as `relevant`/`non-relevant` for the class `C`

Both `SVM-text` and `SVM-image` produce an estimate of the probability of the analyzed content (text or image) of being relevant for the class `C`. Given this, I am able to state whether the text is relevant for `C` and the image is relevant for `C`.

However, these estimates are valid for segments of the original sample (either the text or the image), while it is not clear how to obtain a general opinion on the whole original sample (text+image). How can I combine conveniently the opinions of the two classifiers, so as to obtain a classification for the whole original sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you can do one of two things:

1. **Combine features** from both classifiers. I.e., instead of `SVM-text` and `SVM-image` you may train single `SVM` that uses both - textual and visual features.
2. Use [**ensemble learning**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning). If you already have probabilities from separate classifiers, you can simply use them as weights and compute weighted average. For more sophisticated cases there are Bayesian combiners (each classifier has its prior), boosting algorithms (e.g. see [AdaBoost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdaBoost)) and others.

Note, that ensembles where initially created for combining different learners, not different sets if features. In this later case ensembles have advantage mostly in cases when different kinds of features just can't be combined in a single vector efficiently. But in general, combing features is simpler and more straightforward.

Comment: I have read something about ensemble learning (see scientific paper http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=1105916&tag=1). However, it is not clear to me how to apply them. `SVM-text` is returning a probability of belonging to class `C`, and the same holds for `SVM-image`. Is it sufficient to average them? You talk about weighted average: how to select weights?

Comment: There's huge number of ways to incorporate weights. In simplest case of binary classification you can use equal weights for both answers (from image- and text-based classifiers) and thus simply average probabilities. For multinomial classification you can treat probabilities themselves as weights and compute probability for each class separately. Or you can use adaptive weights like in AdaBoost. Or anything else. Just start reading about weighted ensembles and choose algorithm that in your opinion is the most appropriate for the task.

Comment: Averaging is often not the best approach. I would recommend reading http://mlwave.com/kaggle-ensembling-guide/

Comment: It might be interesting to extract features from both modalities and apply a single SVM so it would be able to find interactions between text and image features.